# Finding a replacement for "Schwalbe No.19 40/62-584/635" tube

Tags: tire

I look for a punctureproof tube to replace the one delivered with my Cube Attention model. My understanding I should shop the new tube ideally by the ETRTO code.

The old tube is signed as "Schwalbe No. 19 - 28"/29" - 40/62-584/635". Now what is exactly the ETRTO code here?

Comment: Increased resistance against punctures is usually achieved by special tires and not tubes. No 19 ist a standard tube from Schwalbe which are usually of good quality. From my experience a thicker tube does not help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 40/62-584/635

Means the tube will fit ETRTO 584 to 635 rims, and 40 to 62mm wide tires.

Inner tubes don't have an exact ETRTO code because they fit a range of rim diameters and tire widths. Tubes from different manufacturers (and single manufacturers at different times) will have different ranges, so buying an exact replacement model can be difficult.

As ojs said, find the ETRTO size of the tire then buy a tube that accommodates that size in its acceptable range.

Answer (score 5):

Schwalbe No. 19 is an inner tube and 28"/29" - 40/62-584/635 is a range of tire sizes it fits. If you are replacing the tube, look up tire size on the tire and buy a tube that fits it. If you are replacing the tire, again look up the size on the tire and buy a matching one.

Comment: I need to understand the ERTRO corresponding to this code, "40/62-584/635" first.

Comment: As said in the other answer, 40 to 62 mm width and 584 to 635 mm diameter. Usually the dash denotes range but for some reason ETRTO reserved it to separator between width and diameter so this odd notation had to be invented.